# iOS: Monitor a Socket Connected to a Wifi Device while app is in Background

Tags: ios, sockets, background

Some background: We have recently taken over development of an app for a client from their existing hardware team, this app connects over the wireless network to a pellet grill with a wireless board and custom controller. In iOS they communicate using CFSockets, as of now it's a lot of serialized bytes exchanges.

What we need is some service that can monitor the data sent from the Grill even when the App remains in the background. The reason we need this is we monitor things like low fuel warnings and food probe temperature.

An example use case: The user starts up the grill, sets a profile and returns inside. The app goes into the background. One of the steps of the profile is to Flip the meat when it reaches a certain internal temperature. We need to be able send a local notification and play an audible sound when the meat is ready to be flipped, even if the phone is locked.

I think we need to use the external-accessory background mode, but I am unsure how I would set up a separate thread/task that runs even when the phone is asleep. The most important thing is that we need to be able to perform lightweight logic on data received from a socket and notify the user when certain conditions are met that we cannot predict ahead of time. For longer durations of grilling this could be over several hours.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what I should be using and any possible road-blocks ahead?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like VoIP background mode may work for you. It allows iOS to take ownership of your sockets and wake your app when data arrives

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that. If anyone else has ideas please keep them coming. :D

Comment: It seems the app may be denied if it doesn't offer any VoIP services but uses that background mode. Hopefully the VoIP approach works just with a different background mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we probably won't be able to solve this problem until we can use the Grill to send push notifications from a server.

"Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS). Our engineers have reviewed your request and have concluded that there is no supported way to achieve the desired functionality given the currently shipping system configurations."

As of 4/15/2015:
We had to make the grills smarter and relay the alert through the push notification service. It works, but it would have worked better if Apple allowed us to maintain a background connection.